# You called the script without passing the environment variables, please run as sudo with -E switch

Tags: shell-script, debian, software-installation, sudo

I feel like this is a really dumb question but I have tried everything I could. I am trying to install a program called [avr4l](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-studio-linux-0) but when I try to run `sudo ./install.sh`, I get this message:

```
You called the script without passing the environment variables, please run as sudo with -E switch.
```

So I tried it with the -E switch:

```
sudo -E ./install.sh
```

But I still get the same error. Here are some of the other commands I tried:

```
sudo -E ./install.sh
sudo -e ./install.sh
sudo ./install.sh -E
sudo ./install.sh -e
```

All of which receive the same error.

Can anybody help me with this?

I am using Debian 9 on a modified Optiplex 755

Thank you for your time!
Nikolai.

Comment: Please put into the question what you did in order to follow step #1 of the installation instructions.

Comment: Looking at the `install.sh` script, it seems that the only environment variable it cares about is `JAVA_HOME` - were you able to successfully add that to your `/etc/environment` and source the file, as described in the installation instructions?

Comment: Please take the time for the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [install script](https://github.com/abdalmoniem/AVR4L/blob/master/Binaries/Linux/install.sh) prints this message when the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` isn't set (line 18). The [README](https://github.com/abdalmoniem/AVR4L/blob/master/README.md#installation-and-running) tells you how you're supposed to do that. You either haven't followed that manual, or it's working in a different way on your system; in the latter case you could try to set the variable in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` instead, depending on what's used by your distribution. It may also be necessary to preceed the line with `export`; at least it won't hurt to do that:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry. I did read the manual but I must have missed a big fat chunk because I think I have got it working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

It's expecting some variable(s). You need to figure out what variables exactly. Either consult a readme there or just read the script. Once you know the variable(s) to be set, try either:

```
sudo VAR=value ./install.sh
```

or

```
sudo ./install.sh -E VAR=value
```

(or something like this; maybe `-E value`).